# CkEditior5 Annotations Buttons are not working

Tags: ckeditor5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFMzV.png)I am currently integrating CKEditor 5 inline annotations, and it is functioning properly. However, I am encountering issues with writing replies as the reply fields are disabled, and the cancel button is also not functioning.

I have read the documentation numerous times, but unfortunately, I haven't found anything helpful.